# Alamofire iOS - remove cached images after time

Tags: ios, swift, caching, alamofire

I'm using alamofire to download images and cache them.

I'm using `UIImageView+AlamofireImage.swift`

with the method -

```
imageView.af_setImage(withURL: url)
```

I need images to be cached for 3 days and then to be deleted, WITHOUT deleting the ones that are 1 day old - which means I can't just delete all the cache every 3 days.

my question is - can I set the cache files expiration date on the client side? maybe by using an alamofire parameter or something?

I know that it can be done from the server but I have no access, It needs to be set from the application.